# Error: no applicable method for dplyr functions applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi

I am getting the following error after the latest update of R packages:

```
Error in UseMethod("db_has_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'db_has_table' applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbCreateTable(con, "iris", iris)
dbAppendTable(con, "iris", iris)

# this works:
dbListTables(con)
[1] "iris"

# this does not work:
db_list_tables(con)

Error in UseMethod("db_list_tables") : 
  no applicable method for 'db_list_tables' applied to an object of class "c('SQLiteConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"
```

In particular, I updated DBI from 1.1.0 to 1.1.2

dplyr is 1.0.9 (this is current version as of today) and worked before the DBI update.

Please help resolving this error

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Chirag I just use `dbListTables` as stated in the example code